# Testing generators with cucumber and aruba

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bundler, aruba

I've just released a gem on github and I wrote integrations test with aruba gem. However I can't run features because it behaves differently from command line.

If i run the features rails can't find my generator, if I repeat the same steps on the commandline they run flawlessly.

This is a failing feature

```
Background: A new rails application has been created with my gem
  Given a rails application named "my_app" exists
  And this gem is installed in that application

@announce
Scenario: Installation using default values
  When I successfully run `rails generate google_authentication:install`
  # this is needed because rails g returns 0 when can't find the generator
  And the output should not contain "Could not find generator"
```

And this is the code which implements background steps

```
Given /^a rails application named "([^\"]*)" exists$/ do |app_name|
  @app_name = app_name
  Given "I successfully run `rm -rf #{app_name}`" # added to ensure that the working directory is clean
  And "a directory named \"#{app_name}\" should not exist"
  And "I successfully run `rails new #{app_name}`"
  And "I cd to \"#{app_name}\""
end

When /^this gem is installed in that application$/ do
  gempath = File.expand_path('../../../', __FILE__)
  Given "I append to \"Gemfile\" with \"gem 'gem-name', :path => '#{gempath}'\""
  And "I successfully run `bundle check`"
end
```

I tried to debug and I found that if I change the `bundle check` command with `bundle install` and I capture the output, my gem is not listed in the bundle. As a consequence if I write a `rails g --help` step my generator is not there. However devise gem and generators are there (devise is listed as requirement in my gem. So it seems that bundler/rails is not loading all inside aruba steps.

I think that this is a bug with Aruba or Bundler, I opened [an issue for aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/issues/77) but still no answers.

Full code is on [Github](https://github.com/fabn/google_authentication)

Last thing I've already seen and tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445736/aruba-cucumber-tests-ruby1-9-2) but with no luck

Comment: i would hate to see the test fail when for some reason #{app_name} becomes a blank string...

Comment: Having a similar problem. I maintain an old gem to support rails 3.1 >. The problem is bundle install command fails. While the output shows that it is installed, when I check for Gemfile.lock, it does not exist! It's also not an aruba issue because I am not using aruba gem.

Comment: I realized I've been doing it the wrong way. Check out how I wrote my tests: https://github.com/bridgeutopia/textile_editor_helper . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of all of those steps you wrote which are a bit deprecated in cucumber.

Try something like this:

```
Given /^a rails application named "([^\"]*)" exists$/ do |app_name|
  FileUtils.mkdir_p("tmp")
  system("rm -rf tmp/#{app_name}")
  system("rails new tmp/#{app_name}")
  system("ln -s ../../../lib/generators tmp/#{app_name}/lib")
  @current_directory = File.expand_path("tmp/#{app_name}")
end
```

You have to create a link to the directories. It makes more sense than doing bundle install which you shouldn't attempt testing using cucumber.

Comment: I'm gonna try and let you know